# what is the best headphone with a good bass for $100

Tags: headphones, purchase-advice

I'm trying to buy some good headphone (I would prefer if it was Bluetooth but I don't mind if it wasn't wireless), I'm listening to House music especially dubstep and trance, so the bass should be good, I looked for some in Amazon and I found Koss BT540i but in reviews someone said that the bass is bad.

My budget is around $100.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try the Sennheiser HD 558 they have a great frequency responce and an overall great sound for the price, 15hz to 28mhz, 50 Ohm, 300cm cable and dynamic drivers, remember, you might want good bass, but not lots of it, these headphones would serve you well for the 100 dollar price point

Comment: thanks for the downvote and not stating the issue with my answer, really appriciate it

Comment: Luuk - I don't know who downvoted, but I would imagine it was for answering an off topic question, thus encouraging more off topic questions. Don't worry about it.

Comment: oh yea, forgot about the 'no consumer' rule for a sec, my fault, thanks for pointing it out